# How to export all collumns from jabref?

Tags: html, jabref

I'm using jabref to manage my references.
The inssue that I'm facing is that I want to export all the columns that I've added.
Like:
[image]
But when I opened the exportted file, there are just the default fixed, that doesn't change:
[image]

I would like to export them all does anybody know if is it possible?

PS: I'm using the export tool from jabref to HTML  going to : `file > export > export all entries`

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that there is a function to export displayed columns.
The solution is to create an export filter referencing the relevant columns.
See [the dedicated help about custom exports](https://docs.jabref.org/collaborative-work/export/customexports)

Comment: In the link you've send me is telling to go to `Options → Manage custom exports` but in my Options menu here there is just `manage content selectors` is the same thing ? because Iḿ not showing what it's said : ```To add a new custom export filter, open the dialog box Options → Manage custom exports, and click Add new. A new dialog box will appear, allowing you to specify a name for the export filter (which will appear as one of the choices in the File type dropdown menu of the file dialog when you use the File → Export menu choice in the JabRef window)```

Comment: I've exported to an `ods` sheet it worked in parts because its showing some tables `Custom1, Custom2,Custom3,Custom4,Custom5` why is it ?
`